# androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1 error

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

**I have this error when running app**

Execution failed for task ':flutter_native_splash:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_native_splash:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform versionedparcelable-1.1.1.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Could not find versionedparcelable-1.1.1.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/versionedparcelable/versionedparcelable/1.1.1/versionedparcelable-1.1.1.jar

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flutter version 3+ use `flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.4` if your flutter version is less than 3 then use 2.1.6 or below. Your version of native splash seems to be very old which might be incompatible with other packages in your source.

Comment: it does not work

Comment: what's the error now?

Comment: the same as before

Comment: Try flutter clean and build again